# Аргумент функции не распознается при setInterval в JS

Tags: setinterval, javascript

В alert'е должно отображаться 123456, но, к сожалению, отображается **undefined** :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _query(id) {
 setInterval(function() {
  $.get('/query.php', function(data) {
   if(data == 1) alert(id); // undefined
  });
 }, 10000);
}

_query(123456);
</script>
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что код точностью совпадает с тем, где у вас `undefined`?
Данный код полностью рабочий.

Comment: @lampa, уверен, только у меня сетинтервал вызывается по клику, т.е <a href="javascript://" onclick="_query(123456);">click</a>

Comment: Все же что-то недоговариваете.

Comment: @KaZaца, договариваю. Просто мне в последнее время не нравится setInterval, то он запускается много раз, несмотря на clearInterval. Приходится делать мистические проверки, то ещё что-то. Много тем создавал ;) Вообщем опять набыдлокодил я, ну да ладно.

Comment: именно поэтому лучше избегать его использования:

    setTimeout(function loop(){
        console.log('looping');
        setTimeout(loop, 500);
    }, 500)

Comment: @Spectre, как потом остановить setTimeout - неизвестно.

Comment: более чем известно:

    var counter = 0,    
        timer = setTimeout(function loop(){            
            if(++counter > 5){ // 5 итераций
                clearTimeout(timer)
            } else {         
                console.log('looping');
                timer = setTimeout(loop, 500);
            }            
        }, 500)

Comment: @Spectre, if(++counter > 5){ // 5 итераций, а это для чего?

Comment: разве не очевидно? условие завершения "цикла"

Comment: а разве без clearTimeout он не завершится? Почитайте уже про доки, хватит гадать.

Comment: @KaZaца, естественно завершиться, это просто демонстрационный вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _query(id) {
 setInterval(function(id) {
  $.get('/query.php', function(data) {
   if(data == 1) alert(id); // undefined
  });
 }, 10000, id);
}
_query(123456);
</script>
```

Чтобы передать аргумент в функцию, вызываемую через setInterval, передайте этот аргумент в сам setInterval после 2 аргумента - задержки выполнения.

Приведенный выше код у меня лично сработал.

Comment: он сработает и без передачи id в вызываемую функцию.